# Manipulation of equation from ratio of two variables to difference between them

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation of the form $x_1/x_2=\exp(a)$. I'd like to manipulate the equation so that the difference between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is a function of their average, i.e. $x_1 - x_2 = f(\bar{x})$, where $\bar{x}=(x_1 + x_2)/2$.

I saw the solution in a paper (provided without steps) to be $2\bar{x}(\exp{(a)} - 1)/(\exp{(a)} + 1)$ but I'm unable to do it myself. I'd be grateful if somebody could show the steps to get to the solution (this is not homework, I'd just like to understand the steps).

Here are the steps I tried:

$$
x_1-x_2 = \exp{(a)}x_2-x_2
$$

Then I tried to use the definition of the average ($x_2 = 2\bar{x}-x_1$):

$$
x_1 - x_2 = \exp{(a)}(2\bar{x}-x_1) - (2\bar{x}-x_1) = x_1(1 - \exp{(a)}) + 2\bar{x}(\exp{(a)} - 1)
$$

At this point, I was stuck because of the $x_1$ on the right hand side.

Comment: What have you tried? Remember to show your work and thoughts on the problem, otherwise your question will probably be poorly received in this forum

Comment: @jjagmath Good point, I will expand my question shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to think about it is to solve the system of equations in $x_1, x_2$:
\begin{align}
x_1-x_2&=f(\bar x)\\
x_1+x_2&=2\bar x
\end{align}

to get $x_1=\dfrac{2\bar x + f(\bar x)}{2}$, $x_2 =\dfrac{2\bar x - f(\bar x)}{2}$

Then $\exp(a) =\dfrac{\dfrac{2\bar x + f(\bar x)}{2}}{\dfrac{2\bar x-f(\bar x)}{2}}$ and solve this equation for $f(\bar x)$.

Comment: That's pretty clever and actually more intuitive, I think.

Comment: Notice that it's also more general, since if you have other equation relating $x_1$ and $x_2$ instead of $x_1/x_2=\exp(a)$ you could still substitute $x_1$ and $x_2$ and solve for $f(\bar x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take $x_1/x_2=\exp(a)$ and substract $1$ to get $\dfrac{x_1-x_2}{x_2}=\exp(a)-1$.

Take $x_1/x_2=\exp(a)$ and add $1$ to get $\dfrac{x_1+x_2}{x_2}=\exp(a)+1$.

Dividing we get $$\dfrac{x_1-x_2}{x_1+x_2}=\dfrac{\exp(a)-1}{\exp(a)+1}$$ so $$x_1-x_2=(x_1+x_2)\dfrac{\exp(a)-1}{\exp(a)+1}=2\bar{x}\dfrac{\exp(a)-1}{\exp(a)+1}$$